# How to write a method that uses lot of Calendar's set methods in a compact way

Tags: kotlin

I have the following code to get the difference of the date. However since I'm new to kotlin, I don't know any other way to write the following code in a smaller/compact way....Is there a way to make this big code small? Some sample code or hint will be lovely! I would love to hear from you!

```
   fun getDiffWeek(year1: Int, month1: Int): Int {
        return getDiffWeek(year1, month1, 1)
    }

    fun getDiffWeek(year1: Int, month1: Int, day1: Int): Int {
        val calendar = GregorianCalendar.getInstance() as GregorianCalendar
        calendar.set(Calendar.YEAR, year1)
        calendar.set(Calendar.MONTH, month1 - 1)
        calendar.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, day1)
        calendar.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, 0)
        calendar.set(Calendar.MINUTE, 0)
        calendar.set(Calendar.SECOND, 0)
        calendar.set(Calendar.MILLISECOND, 0)

        val currCalendar = GregorianCalendar.getInstance() as GregorianCalendar
        currCalendar.timeInMillis = System.currentTimeMillis()
        currCalendar.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, 0)
        currCalendar.set(Calendar.MINUTE, 0)
        currCalendar.set(Calendar.SECOND, 0)
        currCalendar.set(Calendar.MILLISECOND, 0)

        val diffTime = calendar.timeInMillis - currCalendar.timeInMillis
        return if (diffTime < 0) {
            -1
        } else Math.ceil(diffTime / ONE_WEEK.toDouble()).toInt()

    }
```

Comment: You can use `apply` to avoid `calendar.` qualifiers: https://proandroiddev.com/the-tldr-on-kotlins-let-apply-also-with-and-run-functions-6253f06d152b. You can use `import ...Calendar.*` to avoid  `Calendar.` qualifiers (I don't know what else it contains, so it may be a bad idea, since it'll pollute your namespace).

Comment: It also seems that there are constructors which do what you want: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/GregorianCalendar.html

Comment: On a side note you may want to use the classes and methods from the `java.time.*` package which are much more convenient and up to date (available since java 8) instead of `Calendar`